# How to unpick the selected gallery in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps

My form is manually created for edit and create new data in Powerapps it means that they go into one screen. However whenever I try to create new lists the previously selected gallery variables keep on showing up. I have tried to input

```
UpdateContext({Circle1:BodyDashboard.Selected});UpdateContext({Circle1: {}});Navigate(CreateManPower,ScreenTransition.Fade);
```

for the button on new data but still don't work. Anyone has idea on powerapps?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the form mode to FormMode.New or try resetting the form on button select as  ResetForm(FormName).

Answer (score 0):

I use `Set` for this scenario. Similar to `UpdateContext`, but it will pass the variable to all screens whereas `UpdateContext` only works on the given screen (unless you pass it to another screen via `Navigate`).

`OnVisible` of the screen with the Gallery:

```
Set(varResetGallery, glrTest.Selected);
Set(varResetGallery, {})
```

This, in essence, toggles the Gallery's selected record.

**Then** set `glrTest.Default` to `varResetGallery` (<--this is key)